# How to set focus for bootstrap drop down box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down box taken from "silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select.,"
Here I need to focus to that drop down on page load because i don't want to click to that drop down to set the focus., once the page loaded then directly the focus should move to the drop down

I have tried the below code

```html
<select class="form-control show-tick" data-live-search="true" name="lstClass" id="lstClass" >
    <option>Class1</option>
    <option>Class2</option>
    <option>Class1</option>
</select>

<script>
    document.form1.lstClass.focus();    
</script>
```

Comment: does this work? `document.getElementById('lstClass').focus()`

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio no its not working

Comment: @BrindhaBaskaran which version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `autofocus` for this. This attribute sets the focus to the first element that has this attribute on page load:

```html
    <select autofocus> 
      <option> TEST</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: thanks for answer. autofocus is working but my drop down is with search option, i need the focus with search, by using autofocus i cant able to search

Comment: This has not been specified in the original post. Please explain your problem in more detail and what you tried, why it isn't working and what you expect the result to be.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `autofocus` to the `select` tag

```html
<select autofocus class="form-control show-tick" data-live-search="true" name="lstClass" id="lstClass" >
    <option>Class1</option>
    <option>Class2</option>
    <option>Class1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for answer. autofocus is working but my drop down is with search option, i need the focus with search, by using autofocus i cant able to search

Comment: @BrindhaBaskaran Hello What do you mean by `search`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by 2 ways using `autofocus` and `jquery`

```js
$('select[name="lstClass"]').focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control show-tick" data-live-search="true" name="lstClass" id="lstClass" >
    <option>Class1</option>
    <option>Class2</option>
    <option>Class1</option>
</select>
```